# I need to configure haproxy with two ssl ports

Tags: ssl, redirect, haproxy

I have two server
Having the same URL but the port number may changes
I want to Perform Redirection of These two URLs enters by the client to https.
if I enter my first URL i.e example.com then I want to it will redirect to example.com

if I enter second URL i.e example.com:8080 then I want to it will be redirected to then example.com:8080
See My Configurations

```
frontend www-HTTP
bind *:80
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
default_backend tcp-backend
mode tcp

frontend TCP-HTTP
bind *:8080
bind *:8443 ssl crt /etc/apache2/ssl/paritech.pem
reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
default_backend www-backend
mode tcp

backend www-backend
redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
server dev.example.com 192.168.1.120:8080 check

backend TCP-backend
redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
server qa.example.com 192.168.1.120:80 check
```

How can I redirect 8080 over 8443 for HTTPS...